# source indicator, dual schottky passive load transfer switch

Tags: current, schottky, indicator

A dual schottky diode powers a load from either battery or off-the-shelf power supply.

How to indicate which sources are providing current to the load?  None, one, the other, or both.

Yet draw less than 10 µA from the battery while the power supply is on.

(My immediate use case is battery backup for a domestic appliance, which is DC, 8 V ± 1 V, 20 mA to 800 mA, using an MBR20100CT selected from parts box, but I'd like to generalise.  I'm also remote, so have a preference for stocked parts; passives, transistors, diodes, mosfets, attiny85, LEDs.)

Comment: The other answers seem overly complicated. I think all you need is two comparators. Forward bias on the diode tells you that that supply is supplying current. You could also just compare the two input voltages (before the diode). If supply is higher than battery, you are drawing from supply, and vice-versa. Ignore the transient case where both supply and battery are supplying current. All LED's should be powered from supply, not battery. If the device is off, and supply is absent, do you want any LED on? It will drain the battery just to supply indication. This will have to exceed 10 uA.

Comment: Also, I want to challenge you. Instead of doing it the way you are doing it, you should use a single shottky for the power supply, and a PFET for the battery. PFET gate can be wired to power supply. When power supply fails, battery PFET turns on. You might need back-to-back PFET's to prevent charging of battery (through body diode). Or you could keep the second shottky if you don't mind the drop. It all depends on range of voltages of power supply and battery type and voltage and whatnot.

Comment: Diode reverse current increases by **TYREE** ordeers of magnitude from 25C to 125C. 0.15 mA to 150 m !!! at rated voltage. [Datasheet here](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/MBR2020CT-MBR20100CT(TO-220AB).pdf) | see addition to my answer re long tailed pair.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dual one-of-four MUX, a CMOS op-amp and a microcontroller. Microcontroller wakes up every second or whatever, powers up the CMOS op-amp and charges C2 to the voltage across D1, connects C2 to the op-amp, measures it, repeats for D2, and compares the two voltages to the desired point on the I-V curve of the diode (if less than xx volts, assume it's conducting). If the diode is reverse biased it will read ~0 on the ADC.  Micro then does "something" for display (Russell has listed a whole bunch of things, I'd add you could just briefly flash a very efficient LED). Then go back to sleep, rinse and repeat.

'One of two' mux shown below, extension is obvious.. warning, this circuit exceeds the supply voltages of the analog switches by a Schottky diode drop, so some may get an attack of the vapors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsIR3K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.  Understood.  (Can get CD4052.  Have CD4066 which could be used at a pinch.)

Answer (score 0):

Any display that operates at 10 uA is liable to use passive redirection of ambient light rather than radiate 'signal energy'.

An LCD display allows near zero static current and may well be the most 'high tech' solution.

As does a latched relay or airline display board electromechanical shutter thingy - lots of fun, if not actually normal fare. If this is a one off rather than an N off and size is not a vast issue, and a couple of nice yellow eyeballs sounds attractive I could pry a few out of the bus destination panel I was given a while ago and send them 'across the pond'.

A motor based system offers zero current when not in use.
Options include stepper-motor based which has the advantages of open loop mechanical position holding and pulse and forget switching, and very small versions are available.

Other motor solutions where the motor per se does not provide absolute positional certainty could use position sensors (reed better than hall due to current issues), or "drive until contact state changes" sensing.

A screw thread allows multi state indication.
End to end  drive gives two states and intermediate states can be sensed or various ways or hoped for with timing.

A very elegant and accessible motor based system which is not apparently one t fist glance is to use an automotive fuel gauge type meter where position is a function of drive signals **BUT** the last valid position locks when power is removed. (eg in a car when the gauge shows1/4 full it usually continues to do so when power is removed - as long as you do not have one of these new fangled electronic ones).

An RC type servo offers a cheap easily implemented nearly perfect fit "motor based" solution.

The keen and artistic could pump coloured fluids, inflate (ultra low pressure to prevent state loss) balloons or drive visually phase changed phase change material - that could actually be quite a good idea - but getting bidirectional phase change drive may be harder.

The more I think about it the more "possibilities" emerge.
I'd better stop :-).

---

See

Basic comparator across diodes should work. When battery is on comparator switches one way and other when diode is reverse biased. If comparator Vcommon_mode does not exceed V+ (some do) then you can resistively divide down the voltages. With DC 8V supply and 1 meg in upper divider legs you could have say 100k in lower leg to get ~= 100k input resistance.  For say 400 mV across on diode this gives 0.4V/11 ~= 35 mV at comparator which is enough greater than Voffset typical dir eg cheap LM393 as to be OK. (Or LM324).

---

If you want to stay discrete you can use a simple long tailed pair as comparator. I had a simple LTP save a situation that nothing else handled. I had perhaps 12V-200V AC inputs and wanted to track zero crossings. High resistance inputs to transistor bases switched transistor pair at zero crossing.

Digs ....
Here we are. March 2006 it claims.
Transistors had provisions for base pulldowns but not installed.
5V supply (I think)
SPDIN1, SPDIN2 were 2 phases on a 3 phase exercise bike / elliptical alternator.
Waveforms start sinusoidal then go to trapezoidal as speed/load combo saturates laminations.
BUT the alternator load is a 20 kHz PWM'd resistor. Load at max speed and 100% duty cycle pWM was 500 Watts +.  So combination of  variable V,variable frequency, variable wave shape and dominating 20 kHz PWM made for a horrendous signal to get zero crossings from.
This simple circuit worked superbly. This was used to derive speed signal. Saved client the cost of a reed switch, magnet, wiring run and plug/socket.
[**Possibly one in here**](http://www.infiniti.com.au/55-366-thickbox/vg30-infiniti-cross-trainer01-domestic-.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Chuckle.  Thanks.  Hadn't thought of a 10 µA indicator limit.  That would be fun, but not what I intended.  I've checked my question wording, and rephrase; no limit on current draw for indicator, just a limit on draw from one particular source when the other source is available.

Answer (score 0):

I want to toss something out for you to consider.  You mention 10uA current consumption.  Be aware that the leakage current in many (most) Schottky diodes far exceeds 10uA.

Comment: Also, diode leakage has a temperature coefficient. Do not know if that matters to you. But the reverse leakage will go up a lot if the diode is hot.